# How do I implement NTLM authentication using Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I would like to use Puppeteer to automate testing with a site that requires NTLM authentication. It appears the page.authenticate() API only accepts a username and password but no domain. Does anyone have any suggestions or tips?

Answer (score 0):

Until now, the only way that worked for me was using cntlm:

1. Install cntlm. http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/
2. Configure cntlm, following the Configuration hints in the page
3. Run cntlm
4. Then use it in Puppeteer like this

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            "--proxy-server=localhost:3133" // the cntlm proxy defined in cntlm.conf
        ]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://example.com');

    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshots/example.png' });
    browser.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendation! I haven't yet been able to test out the use of cntlm but will update this post when I do...

Comment: I have to access to a intranet Sharepoint website that requires NTLM authentication. No need of a proxy to go to it... I tried to play with cntlm, without success. If you have any more advice on how to configure it exactly, it will be appreciated. Thanks